# fetching data from data core ios

Tags: ios, database, core-data, fetch

I'm working on ios application that when clicking add button it takes me to another view controller to fill my information and save them in core data how can i fetch this data and post it in Tableview any help ?

Comment: have you read any tutorials to this? ^^ inform yourself about `NSFetchRequest` and `NSFetchedResultsController` for easier handling ;)

Comment: ok thanks my problem is that they are 2 different view controllers and I'm not understanding how to use object from another view controller

Comment: this are basics ^^ use google or read the apple API ;) there are a lot of free code examples that will help you. just use the existing sources at the internet :) for the `NSManagedObjectContext` you will need a singleton or maybe write directly a ModelHandler class (as singleton) where you handle all core-data operations. There are a lot ways to do, just ask google for sample projects for core-data ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To save the data (in your view controller where you get the data from)**

in your .m file add

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}
```

and in your save action add

```
- (IBAction)savePressed:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        NSManagedObject *newData = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"StoredData" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [newData setValue:textField.text forKey:@"dataattribute"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Save Failed! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

}
```

**in your table view controller**

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}
```

in your view did appear

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"entityName"];
    arrayData = [[moc  executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];


    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *data = [arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [data valueForKey:@"dataattribute"]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks my problem is that they are 2 different view controllers and I'm not understanding how to use object from another view controller

Comment: @mowi Please see my edit, i have added how to save the data from one view controller and then load it into the table view

Comment: sorry my question may be stupid but can i know " arraydata " how to use it?

Comment: @mowi The arrayData is the NSMutableArray which you should declare in your .h file

Comment: unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: @mowi Click on your cell in your storyboard, go to the attribute inspector and where its says identifier add Cell

Comment: I'm using xib not storyboard is there another way to chat?

Comment: @mowi There is but you need 20 or more reputation, unless your on Facebook or something and we can chat on that?

Comment: want to chat facebook i really need ur help ?

Comment: what is ur facebook ?

Comment: Or you could search for the error message: "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib". If you can't figure it out, post a new question.

Comment: @Chris1994 hey chris can u help me in casting an object into class ?